# laravel new blog not work mockery/mockery 1.4.0

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Today I wanted to create a new project with Laravel with this command

```
laravel new blog
```

But I get this error

```
Crafting application...
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for mockery/mockery 1.4.0 -> satisfiable by mockery/mockery[1.4.0].
    - mockery/mockery 1.4.0 requires php ^7.3.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.23) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

Why should php7.3 be read when Laravel himself says at least php7.2.5 ???

Comment: Odd. Current version of Laravel only requires Mockery 1.3. https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5639581ea56ecd556cdf6e6edc37ce5795740fd7/composer.json#L21

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Run `composer update`.

**The reason:**

Your PHP version is too low. You've got 7.2.23 installed, and `mockery/mockery` 1.4 requires 7.3.0

The best solution is to upgrade your PHP version. Alternatively, you can reduce mockery's version to [1.3.1](https://packagist.org/packages/mockery/mockery#1.3.1), which only requires PHP 5.6 or above.

[My bug report can be found here](https://github.com/laravel/installer/issues/117)

As of 2020-05-21, the zip files that `laravel new ___` uses will try to install `mockery/mockery` version 1.4. This won't work with versions of PHP below 7.3. In order to fix this, run `composer update`, and mockery will be downgraded to a compatible version.

Comment: How to change mockery / mockery version to 1.3.1

Comment: Change it in composer.json then run composer update.

Comment: While upgrading PHP will work, the Laravel docs indicate Laravel (and its dependencies) only requires 7.2.5+, and by default it only requires Mockery 1.3. I'm not sure how OP has messed it up to force v1.4 to be required.

Comment: @ceejayoz `laravel/installer` downloads [this zip file](cabinet.laravel.com/latest.zip), and runs composer install on it. It's true that composer.json only requires `mockery/mockery` of `^1.3.1`, but the composer.lock file in that zip lists `mockery/mockery` version `1.4.0`. A `composer update` would probably fix it. The master branch of `laravel/installer` [is failing on PHP 7.2](https://github.com/laravel/installer/actions/runs/109837512), and I suspect this is the issue. Long story short, I don't think OP messed it up.

Comment: @Joundill Oh interesting, I didn't realize `laravel new` pulled a `composer.lock` down.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem today for new Laravel projects. The `composer.json` file was showing `"mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1"` but still was showing the same error. Delete also the `composer.lock` file and run `composer install`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are trying to create a new laravel project called `blog` this is what I did to fix the error after running `laravel new blog`

1. cd into `blog`
2. run `composer update`
3. Create a `.env` file. You can just make a copy of `.env.example` and rename the copy to `.env`. In case you try to start the dev server using `php artisan serve` and the app launches with a 500 error, run these commands:

   `php artisan key:generate`

   `php artisan cache:clear`

   `php artisan config:clear`

   `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem when trying to create new Laravel applications,I updated php version using the following commands and it worked.

`sudo apt install software-properties-common`

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`

`sudo apt install -y php7.4 php7.4-gd php7.4-mbstring php7.4-xml`

Answer (score 1):

You can just run

`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel <project_name>`

It'll automatically fall-back to `mockery^1.3.1`

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `composer.lock` file and run composer again

`composer install`

Answer (score 0):

I also faced these problems.

> Problem 1
> - Installation request for facade/ignition-contracts 1.0.2 -> satisfiable by facade/ignition-contracts[1.0.2].
> - facade/ignition-contracts 1.0.2 requires php ^7.3|^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.34) does not satisfy that requirement.
>
> Problem 2
> - Installation request for mockery/mockery 1.4.2 -> satisfiable by mockery/mockery[1.4.2].
> - mockery/mockery 1.4.2 requires php ^7.3 || ^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.34) does not satisfy that requirement.
>
> Problem 3
> - facade/ignition-contracts 1.0.2 requires php ^7.3|^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.34) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - nunomaduro/collision v4.2.0 requires facade/ignition-contracts ^1.0 -> satisfiable by facade/ignition-contracts[1.0.2].
> - Installation request for nunomaduro/collision v4.2.0 -> satisfiable by nunomaduro/collision[v4.2.0].

I had deleted the `composer.lock` file and executed `composer install` command.

My problem solved.

Answer (score -2):

This might be stale, the issue here is that the php needs to be updated to version that will be compatible.

- delete the composer.lock file and autoload file in vendor i.e vendor/autoload in your project
- upgrade php version from php.net
- run composer install --no scripts
- run composer update
- php artisan migrate
- php artisan key:generate

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Why should removing `composer.lock` help? What's the reason to run `composer update` directly after `composer install`?

Comment: The reason for deleting Composer.lock file is that it tries to find the compatible versions of your dependencies to fulfil the composer. json file, it will install the exact version of your dependencies. 

In my own case, I cloned a laravel 8 project & my php version was lower, so I deleted the composer.lock & autoload file. 

Run composer install command
Run composer update 

Then I executed migrations Command,             As well as the key: generate command

Comment: Please add **all explanation** to your answer by editing it. Also, explain why removing the lock file should produce any different result than running `composer update`  - both recalculate your dependencies